# Setting variables in C++ through C# structure

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I have a solution with 3 projects. A C# WinForms project which depends on second project which is a C++ DLL. The C++ DLL depends on the third project which is a static library. The static library is C code with C++ classes. The DLL acts as an interop between the C code and C# code.

I need to set the variables used by the static library through C# structure.

I do not have experience in C++/CLI (I have started reading. Examples found on the web do not make sense to me as of now)

So far, I have created a structure in C#. I created a initialized unmanaged memory to hold this struct:

```
IntPtr ptData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(objMyClass.data));//data is the structure I am initializing in the constructor of MyClass
Marshal.StructureToPtr(objPythonInterop.data, ptData, false);
objCPPClass.UpdateData(ptData);//objCPPClass is object to class in DLL. libClass is the object of class in static library
```

This is my structure in C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Data
{
    members here..
}
```

In the DLL, this is the `UpdateData` function:

Header:

```
void UpdateData(IntPtr ptrData);
```

Source:

```
void CPPClass::UpdateData(IntPtr ptrData)
{
    m_lib->UpdateDataInLib(ptrData);// m_lib is object to class in static library
}
```

`UpdateDataInLib` is a function in the Class in Static library. How do I use the ptrData in this function and update the variables? I have a structure in the static library similar to the structure defined in my C# code. How do I cast the ptr to this structure and access the members?

I have a structure in my C++ static library which contains equivalent members of the structure in C#:

```
extern "C"  __declspec(dllexport) typedef struct Data
{
    members here..
}Data, *pData;
```

I need help.

Comment: I can't figure out what you're really asking here... Maybe you could provide some more examples like the code of the structure in C# and in C and the interop call code?

Comment: Doing it this way doesn't make any sense.  Declare the structure in your C++/CLI source file as a `public value struct`.  So you can use it as an argument to your function, instead of IntPtr.  Converting it to the native struct is the boring bit.

Comment: @HansPassant: I have a structure in my C++ code. What I want to know is how do I pass the structure from C# to my static library. How do I define the function for sending the ptr to the structure from C# to my function, cast it to the structure in the static lib and read data from it. If my approach is wrong then what is the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a simpler approach. You don't need dynamic memory allocation *if your DLL doesn't access the structure anymore after the call*. Just put the structure on the stack (you still need `fixed` nevertheless):

```
var data = new objMyClass.data
{
    field1 = value1, // etc
};

unsafe
{
    fixed (objMyClass.data* ptr = &data)
    {
        objCPPClass.UpdateData(new IntPtr(ptr));
    }
}
```

If the structure is long-lived then keep your code as-is but don't forget to free the allocated memory.

Then, on the C++ side, you could just cast:

```
void CPPClass::UpdateData(IntPtr ptrData)
{
    m_lib->UpdateDataInLib(static_cast<pData>(ptrData.ToPointer()));
}
```

But as I don't know the signature of `UpdateDataInLib` I'm not sure about this approach.

Also, you can get rid of the `IntPtr` intermediate step, and just use a pointer.